# Success animation tutorial not running CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm on a tutorial to create a success check mark with an animation.
I already created all the elements such as the box for the alert etc but have trouble with an animation.

Here is the code example I'm following : [Link](https://codepen.io/istiaktridip/pen/BZqaOd)

I tried to do it on my computer putting the HTML part and the JS together and the css in a style.css sheet but doesn't work :(

Here is the HTML document :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>Test</title>

        <script>
            $("button").click(function () {
                $(".check-icon").hide();
                setTimeout(function () {
                $(".check-icon").show();
                }, 10);
                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="success-checkmark">
            <div class="check-icon">
                <span class="icon-line line-tip"></span>
                <span class="icon-line line-long"></span>
                <div class="icon-circle"></div>
                <div class="icon-fix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <center>
                <button id="restart">Restart Animation</button>
            </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

I didn't copy the css as it is the same as is the link and a long code..

It gives me a white screen and a lot of warnings on code inspection :

[image: Code inspection]

As I'm doing something wrong please ?

Thank you for your help,

Jerry

Comment: Have you include jQuery - not in your code sample above, but appears to be essential for the original.

Comment: Looking at the warnings in the styles tab it looks like there are some syntax errors and malformed css in your style.css file

Comment: Thank you @MikeBrockington ! You're right :) But there are still the warnings and it doesn't work :(

Comment: I agree with you @ap.dev ! Some names are in white color instead of green color when it's correct ! But I just copy paste the css code tutorial which is working on codeopen :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is missing from your code, try adding adding it in the `<head>` section.

EDIT: You are also using a wrong .css file. I think you copied the uncompiled SCSS from the tutorial. To fix this, go back to the CodePen example and on the top-right corner of the CSS section open the context menu and click "View Compiled CSS". Then copy the CSS into style.css

Here is a working solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(() => {$("button").click(function () {
                $(".check-icon").hide();
                setTimeout(function () {
                $(".check-icon").show();
                }, 10);
                });});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="success-checkmark">
            <div class="check-icon">
                <span class="icon-line line-tip"></span>
                <span class="icon-line line-long"></span>
                <div class="icon-circle"></div>
                <div class="icon-fix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <center>
                <button id="restart">Restart Animation</button>
            </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Andràs Simon ! I tried to copy paste your code but it doesn't resolve the error :(

Comment: @user1833903 you are also using a wrong .css file. I think you copied the uncompiled SCSS from the tutorial. To fix this, go back to the CodePen example and on the top-right corner of the CSS section open the context menu and click "View Compiled CSS". Then copy the CSS into style.css.

Comment: You're absolutely right ! Thank you @Andras Simon. Could you edit your answer so I put the resolved flag on the answer please ? :)